# How to specify the time as a dependent variable inside 'INTEG' or 'AVG' in LTSPICE?

Tags: ltspice

My aim is to calculate the average and integral of a function. I have already used step function (***.step param...***). Right now I was using ***.meas*** to do this operation, but in that I have to mention the time as ***2 to 3 ns*** or a range like that. I wish to integrate for a range of 2 ns to time taken by the node to reach 1.4 volt (that time varies for different .step inputs). So how can I specify that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Give us a minimal schematic that illustrates the problem. Something concrete to work with. Much good can be had from a clear example.

Comment: I am extremely sorry ,Is the question clear now? @jonk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not so clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but maybe one of the following measurements might help you:

**Case 1:** Integrate \$V(vdd)\$ from \$t=3ns\$ to  \$t=5ns\$

`.meas VAVG AVG V(vdd) FROM 3n to 5n`

**Case 2:** Integrate \$V(vdd)\$ from \$t=3ns\$ until \$V(q_t)=1.4V\$

`.meas VAVG AVG V(vdd) FROM 3n TARG V(q_t)=1.4`

**Case 3:** In case \$V(q_t)=1.4V\$ is reached before \$t=3ns\$, the average will be calculated "backwards", meaning from \$t(V(q_t)=1.4V)\$ to \$t=3ns\$.

If you want to avoid it, you can tell LTSpice to search for \$t(V(q_t)=1.4V)\$ after a given delay:

`.meas VAVG AVG V(vdd) FROM 3n TARG V(q_t)=1.4 TD 3n`